# How to know when sockatpair's SOCK_DGRAM peer socket is closed?

Tags: linux, sockets

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
int main() {
    int s[2];
    socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, s);

    close(s[1]);
    char buf;
    read(s[0], &buf, 1);
}
```

finishes, but with SOCK_DGRAM it hangs.

How to find out when there will be no messages anymore? Why "read" does not return something like ECONNRESET when the peer FDs is closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between SOCK_DGRAM and SOCK_STREAM is that the former is connectionless, which means, among other things, there isn't a connection "state" that is communicated to the other side of the communication.  Therefore, there isn't a concept of that socket being closed by the other side.  The listening server still has a valid endpoint that could receive datagrams, even though in this case it happens to be anonymous and therefore no one else can find it to send things to it.

If you want to have connection state information, you want to use SOCK_STREAM.

See, for example, [this thread](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/fwvdeLjGqNa59ulEvPEU), which discusses a very similar issue.

Comment: OK. Can I just replace SOCK_DGRAM with SOCK_SEQPACKET and assume it will wokr (where SOCK_SEQPACKED is supported)?

Comment: I've not personally used SOCK_SEQPACKET, but yes, that does appear to be the purpose of it and it sounded from that thread like it should work.